# Nginx, SSL, Django, CSRF verification failed (custom port)

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

I am working on a project using Django, nginx and Gunicorn. Everything is good except for POST requests. Django raise a CSRF error.
I dont know what is missing or wrong in my django and/or nginx conf.

**Edit**: I found out what was wrong. Because of my exotic SSL port.
I replaced this line in the 'location /' block:

```
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
```

by:

```
proxy_set_header   Host localhost:8443;
```

Django error:

```
Forbidden (403):
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Reason given for failure:
Referer checking failed - https://localhost:8443/accounts/login/ does not match https://localhost/
```

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       8880;
    server_name  localhost:8443;

    rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

#Gunicorn
upstream project {
    server localhost:8888;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       8443 ssl default_server;
    ssl          on;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      /path/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/file.key;

    #Disable SSLv3
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    ssl_ciphers  "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";


    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:8888;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl https;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port 8443;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host; #Replaced by proxy_set_header   Host localhost:8443;
    }
}
```

and in my settings.py:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Comment: Please accept any answer it if solved your question, or write the solution yourself as an answer and accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try add in your `location /` this:  `proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;`